# Embedded Glassfish and `imqcmd`

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-embedded

We are using an embedded Glassfish Server in our testing environment. We use the `org.glassfish.embeddable.CommandRunner` interface to execute administrative tasks (i.e., what we do with `asadmin` with a standard standalone Glassfish server)

Example:

```
GlassFish glassfish = GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap( bp ).newGlassFish( gfp );
CommandRunner commandRunner = glassfish.getService( CommandRunner.class );
commandRunner.run(
  "create-jms-resource",
  "--restype",
  "javax.jms.Queue",
  "SOME_QUEUE_NAME"
);
```

Now on the command line I am able to set queue options with `imqcmd`. For example

```
imqcmd -u admin -passfile ../password.txt update dst -n SOME_QUEUE_NAME -t q -o maxBytesPerMsg=-1 -f
```

Is there a way to achieve the same with an embedded Glassfish server?

Comment: not sure how useful this is, but that command is in glassfish as so:  `glassfish-4.1/mq/bin/imqcmd`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `imqcmd`, you can use the `asadmin` subcommand `create-jmsdest` to create a JMS physical destination.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/create-jmsdest-1.html) on `create-jmsdest`:

> Typically, you use the `create-jms-resource` subcommand to create a JMS destination resource that has a Name property that specifies the physical destination. The physical destination is created automatically when you run an application that uses the destination resource. Use the `create-jmsdest` subcommand if you want to create a physical destination with non-default property settings.

If you do not specify a Name property for `create-jms-resource`, the name of the physical destination has the same name as the destination resource (replacing any forward slash in the JNDI name with an underscore).

Thus, the `asadmin` commands you want to run are for example:

```
create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.Queue org/example/foo/SomeQueue
create-jmsdest --desttype queue --property maxBytesPerMsg=-1:maxTotalMsgBytes=-1 org_example_foo_SomeQueue
```

Note that (unlike `imqcmd update dst`) `create-jmsdest` does not update the properties if the resource already exists. Therefore, you should not start your application inbetween the two commands, otherwise the resource is automatically created with default properties.

If you have to update properties, you can remove the physical destination first using e.g. `asadmin delete-jmsdest org_example_foo_SomeQueue`.